# Linux remote desktop over SSH (alternative to FreeNX)

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop

I need to find a remote desktop client on my Linux server than works over SSH. We use FreeNX before but it's got outdated and removed from many repos. Which client can you recommend?

Comment: I've used winswitch, but it is dropped now. TightVNC seems still alive

Comment: Do you want to access your Linux server remotely, or do you want to work locally on your Linux server and access other machines remotely? If the latter, do you need RDP support or is RFB (i.e. VNC) support enough?

Comment: It is terminal server with our software. Users will must connect and work on server.

Comment: So you need a GUI and want to work on the remote *desktop* – or you just want to access the command line? Which OS are the clients on? Would a simple SSH tunnel do (opening graphical stuff on the local machine's X-Windows system)?

Comment: Have you tried [nomachine](https://www.nomachine.com/download/linux&id=1)? It was always my favorite for running full shell remotely.

Comment: I need more than 50 users connected. Nomachine has limitations. I want to try x2go.

Comment: @Izzy, thanks for idea. I'll try run software over ssh tunnel.

Comment: Great. What I had in mind you can find in [guettli's answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26042/185). If you've trouble with `-X`, try `-Y` instead (newer method for exporting X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `xrdp` combined with ssh tunneling + compression is much faster than plain X forwarding in SSH.

In spite of the name it internally supports VNC.

For port forwarding over ssh do something like this:

```
ssh -v -C -L localport:127.0.0.1:remotexrdpport user@host.tld
```

Then the client connects to localhost:localport.

Enable `Compression yes` and `CompressionLevel 9` in `.ssh/config` or on commandline to achieve faster forwarding though.

In `xrdp.ini` in `globals` section you should do smth like:

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
...
```

Such a combo works tolerably over relatively slow links. Not as well as `NoMachine` server, but the improvement over plain X forwarding is vast.

Answer (score 1):

How is the latency to your servers? If it is good, the most simple way is:

```
you@pc> ssh -X root@server xeyes
```

Comment: The most of my clients have a 100mb\s. I'll try your advise. Thanks

Comment: That was what I had in mind when asking for clarification on the question (+1 ;) I'd just recommend the `-X` parameter to be replaced by `-Y` (newer method), but the two are "interchangeable": if one causes trouble, try the other.

Comment: Will It use local libs, fonts, printers or remote?

Comment: @NCNecros my guess: it uses local libs and fonts. The printers are from the remote host. AFAIK the application which runs on the remote machine does not know that the display gets exported. But it was just a guess. For my use case it works.

Comment: Since Xwindow protocol shuffles a lot of streams that compress well, I'd add `-C` flag to ssh to enable transparent compression.